# I want to have a testfor command that only teleports a person with a writable_book with a message, and on a certain team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a testfor command that only teleports a player with a specific team and writable_book in their inventory, and in that book on the first page it reads: "Test".
I've tried dozens of commands but couldn't figure it out. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for looks something like this:

```
{Inventory:[{id:minecraft:written_book,tag:{pages:[0:"\"Test\""]}}]}
```

But the teleport command does not support NBT tags. 
However, there is a workaround using scoreboards.

First add a scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add HoldingBook dummy HoldingBook
```

Then run these 2 commands on a fast clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @a HoldingBook 2 {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:written_book,tag:{pages:[0:"\"Test\""]}}]}
/scoreboard players remove @a HoldingBook 1
```

Now, you can teleport the players holing a written book with the word "Test" on the first page, and for example on team blue;

```
/tp @a[score_holdingbook_min=1,team=blue] <your-coords>
```

Hope this helps.